# Check if element has a textarea

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, with a loop how would I be able to check which of the elements below contain a textarea?

Currently I am just looping through each tr

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><textarea></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Find all the textareas, then loop over them and get their `parent()`.

Comment: [:has()](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) Selector, You can try something like `$('tr:has(textarea)')`

Answer (score 0):

Try the code

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
  $(this).find("td textarea").addClass("someClass");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use jquery [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

```
$( "td" ).find( "textarea" );
```

Comment: This is just bringing back in object, regardless of whether this is a text area or not. Is there someway to find true or false?